# are there any reliable plugins for cross browser div scrolling on mobile or do I need to role my own?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I am looking for a reliable way to do cross-browser div scrolling on mobile. Any solution needs to be supported on Android, IOS and Windows phone.

Am I searching for the holy grail? Would it be best for me to create my own solution, or am I attempting the impossible?

Comment: Auto scroll?  Making a div touch scroll-able?  Scroll to specific points or elements in the DIV?

Comment: the standard css overflow:scroll is only reliably supported in the latest os versions as far as I can see when testing with older devices. This is confirmed by this page http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html